# iptables: repetitive identical entries in the iptables on the kubernetes nodes

Tags: kubernetes, iptables

I play around with kubernetes and I have seen that there are a lot of repetitive identical entries in the iptables on the nodes. Any explication why?

```
Chain KUBE-FIREWALL (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             mark match 0x8000/0x8000 /* kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets */
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             mark match 0x8000/0x8000 /* kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets */
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             mark match 0x8000/0x8000 /* kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets */
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             mark match 0x8000/0x8000 /* kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets */
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             mark match 0x8000/0x8000 /* kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets */
....
```

System info:

- os: Debian Stretch
- kernel: 4.15.18-19-pve x86_64 GNU/Linux
- kubelet 1.15.1-00

Installation is done with [ansible](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-kubernetes)

Comment: Can you specify kubernetes version, os, how you installed cluster and any additional details you can provide? Thre was a bug in kubelet 1.3.9 on centos 6 (iptables 1.4.7) - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/37416

Comment: I've updated the question with more details

Answer (score 0):

Followed few times in a row [ansible](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-kubernetes) approach, using the same kernel 4.15.18-19-pve x86_64 GNU/Linux, but not able at all reproduce your problem.

Each time I get(as expected in normal behavior)

```
Chain KUBE-FIREWALL (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets */ mark match 0x8000/0x8000
```

The only way get into the same situation as you - is to manually update iptables duplicating the entries and get rig of references.

If I will find anything interesting - I will let you know.

Comment: I definitely did not manually update the iptables. However, I did reset my k8s cluster 2 or 3 times and re-applied the role. However this does not explain why there are that much of entries

Comment: resetting and re-applying cluster doesnt do this weird thing. Problem in some other place. just did it 2 times and no changes in firewall in `Chain KUBE-FIREWALL`